# VBA code in Access 2010 to check the status of Word Documents only works once before program needs to restart- are there any missing variables?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm not sure whether I can add something that will solve the problem, or end up having to exit each word document individually and see if that helps.

Sub Cmd_Count_Open_Word_Doc_Click()

```
Dim oWord As Object
Dim k As Integer

Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next

Set oWord = Word.Documents
k = oWord.Count

If Documents.Count <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Open Word Documents = " & Documents.Count
    Word.Application.Quit
    GoTo DONE:
End If

NOT_FOUND:

    MsgBox "No Open Word Documents", vbOKOnly

DONE:
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the line `Word.Application.Quit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
Dim wdDoc as Word.Document

' just to check if word is running
On Error Resume Next
Word.Application.Activate
If Err.Number<>0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

' close each document
For Each wdDoc In Word.Documents
    wdDoc.Close
Next

' Quit Word
Word.Application.Quit
```

Comment: It has the same effect, it closes the Word documents and quits Word the first time the button is clicked, but if I open Word again, it does not work; I have to re-open Access in order for it to work again.

Comment: So I didn't really get what you want.
Could you be more precise ?